# I have many actions in toolbar and try to make the font bold for the action which is pressed in PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have made a UI which has various actions in three toolbars. I'm trying to make the font of one action bold when it is pressed and released by mouse. I know how to make the font bold one-by-one. But I'm going to add tens of actions in those three toolbars. How would I be able to do this? Can anyone help me?
Thank you very much.

The main function does make the font of action1 bold.

Main function:

```
from uitest import Ui_MainWindow 
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow

class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        myFont = QtGui.QFont()
        myFont.setBold(True)
        self.ui.Action1.setFont(myFont)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    gui = window()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

UI code

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 330, 151, 71))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 330, 151, 71))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 80, 321, 181))
    self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
    self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
    self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
    MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
    self.toolBar1 = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
    sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
    sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
    sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.toolBar1.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
    self.toolBar1.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(14)
    self.toolBar1.setFont(font)
    self.toolBar1.setObjectName("toolBar1")
    MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar1)
    self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.toolBar.setFont(font)
    self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
    MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)
    MainWindow.insertToolBarBreak(self.toolBar)
    self.toolBar_2 = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(10)
    self.toolBar_2.setFont(font)
    self.toolBar_2.setObjectName("toolBar_2")
    MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar_2)
    MainWindow.insertToolBarBreak(self.toolBar_2)
    self.Action1 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action1.setObjectName("Action1")
    self.Action2 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action2.setObjectName("Action2")
    self.Action3 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action3.setObjectName("Action3")
    self.Action4 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action4.setObjectName("Action4")
    self.Action5 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action5.setObjectName("Action5")
    self.Action6 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action6.setObjectName("Action6")
    self.Action7 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action7.setObjectName("Action7")
    self.Action8 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action8.setObjectName("Action8")
    self.Action9 = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
    self.Action9.setObjectName("Action9")
    self.toolBar1.addAction(self.Action1)
    self.toolBar1.addSeparator()
    self.toolBar1.addAction(self.Action2)
    self.toolBar1.addSeparator()
    self.toolBar1.addAction(self.Action3)
    self.toolBar.addAction(self.Action4)
    self.toolBar.addSeparator()
    self.toolBar.addAction(self.Action5)
    self.toolBar.addSeparator()
    self.toolBar.addAction(self.Action6)
    self.toolBar_2.addAction(self.Action7)
    self.toolBar_2.addSeparator()
    self.toolBar_2.addAction(self.Action8)
    self.toolBar_2.addSeparator()
    self.toolBar_2.addAction(self.Action9)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PushButton"))
    self.toolBar1.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
    self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))
    self.toolBar_2.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar_2"))
    self.Action1.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action1"))
    self.Action2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action2"))
    self.Action3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action3"))
    self.Action4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action4"))
    self.Action5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action5"))
    self.Action6.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action6"))
    self.Action7.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action7"))
    self.Action8.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action8"))
    self.Action9.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Action9"))
```

UI is created by PyQt5 designer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to connect to the `actionTriggered` signal of each toolbar, which sends the action that was clicked. Assuming you only want one action bold at a time, you can then use this to turn on bold for the current action and turn off bold for the previous action (if there is one):

```
class window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        for toolbar in self.findChildren(QtWidgets.QToolBar):
            toolbar.actionTriggered.connect(self.setBoldAction)

    def setBoldAction(self, target, toolbar=None):
        if toolbar is None:
            toolbar = self.sender()
        for action in toolbar.actions():
            if not action.isSeparator():
                font = action.font()
                font.setBold(action is target)
                action.setFont(font)
```

If you want to set the bold action programmatically, you can also do:

```
    self.setBoldAction(action, toolbar)
```

Comment: Thanks for your notice. I'm a little new for the stackoverflow. Now I'm considering to add more functions relying on your code. Such as in the ui, there are three toolbars (toolBar1, toolBar, toolBar_2). Each of them has three actions (total: action1-ation9). At initiation, the first action in each toolbar is bold, that are action1, action4 and action7. When I press one action (like action2), not only the pressed action gets bold, but the action only in the same toolbar gets un-bold and others (action4 and action7) are not changed. I completed initiation. Do you have any idea to do? Thanks.

Comment: @Zhentao. I have updated my answer with a new solution.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works and that's exactly what I want! Thank you!